# Seeing permission issue with showSidebar during onOpen for Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I recently published a new Forms Add-on, and see something that never came up during my testing.

When users first install and auth the Add-on, the sidebar menu pops up as expected (called from onOpen). But when they reload the spreadsheet or re-open it later, it doesn't ooen and I see this exception (send to me via stacklogger):

> You do not have permission to call showSidebar at uiShowPopupMenu(ui:25) at onOpen(utilities:41)

My code looks like this:

```
function uiShowPopupMenu(e)
{
  var fui = FormApp.getUi();

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('uiPopup').evaluate().setTitle("Certify'em");

  fui.showSidebar(html);  
}
```

Any ideas why this might not be working? I have called showSidebar for Spreadsheet Add-ons in this manner in the past with no issues.

Comment: Correction to my original post: "But when they reload the *form*"  (not spreadsheet)

Comment: It might relate to a pre-rendering issue. App-script evaluates all of the code in your .gs files before ui run time. If there are any functions in there that need the users permission before ui rendering is complete it will send the permissions warning. For example getting a users email should only be called from the client, not called while the add on is loading.

Comment: Thanks Supertopoz, but I don't think that's it. The only pre-processing in my uiPopup.html file is to pre-populate a few text strings and to pull in the CSS (per Google's own example).

Comment: Try the [custom sidebar sample code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) in the documentation. "The sidebar can close itself either by calling [**`google.script.host.close()`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#closing_dialogs_and_sidebars_in_google_apps) in the client side of an HTML-service interface or [**`UiInstance.close()`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance#close()) in a UI-service interface. The sidebar cannot be closed by other interfaces, only by the user or itself".

Comment: So the issue turned out to be a chance in functionality just made by Google: 

  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694#comment7

Apparently this is the new normal, now.